# Continued fraction converging to 1.54

Tags: continued-fractions

Consider the fraction $1+\frac{2}{3+\frac{4}{5+\frac{6}{7+\frac{8}{9+\frac{10}{11+\frac{12}{13+...}}}}}}$. This fraction approaches about $1.54$ as you continue it. My question is simple. Does anyone have any idea why this converges to this specific number?

I’ve tried algebraically messing with it, (saying that “$x=1+\frac{2}{3+\frac{4}{5+...}}$” then seeing where it goes.) but to no avail.

I tried to cut off the fraction at different points to try to find patterns in the fractions,( Like cutting off at 7 and solving $1+\frac{2}{3+\frac{4}{5+\frac{6}{7}}}$) but that didn’t work either.

I cannot seem to express it in terms of anything else, either.

Comment: That's $1/(\sqrt{e}-1)\approx 1.5414$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2698904/42969 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%241%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%2B%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7B5%2B%5Cfrac%7B6%7D%7B7%2B%5Cfrac%7B8%7D%7B9%2B%5Cfrac%7B10%7D%7B11%2B%5Cfrac%7B12%7D%7B13%2B...%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1)